# Usar easyuml en Netbans

Tags: netbeans, uml

Tengo instalado la versión 17 de Netbeans para Java y no consigo instalar el plugin del easyUML.Me dice que necesito el unpack 200. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar y decirme como se podría instalar?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor no resumas el error o el mensaje que obtienes, [edit] y añade una descripción más detallada de lo que pasa cuando intentas instalar ese plugin. Intenta que los que lean tu pregunta tengan que adivinar lo menos posible sobre tu problema

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/593411/no-logro-hacer-que-funcione-easyuml-en-netbeans-17-con-java