# No logro hacer que funcione EasyUML en NetBeans 17 con Java

Tags: java, netbeans, uml

He instalado los plugins correctamente, incluso el unpack 200 que requiere para instalarlos. Lo que hago es lo siguiente:

1. tengo un proyecto en Java concluido
2. creo nuevo proyecto UML
3. le doy click derecho a una de las clases de mi proyecto java y luego pongo 'create class diagram.'
4. se crea la clase pero me sale una ventana de error que dice 'Malformed or unredable .cdg file.'

había encontrado una solución que tenia que ver con los caracteres latinos y los signosm pero al modificarlos no funciono.

agradezco la ayuda.